# Serve large file with PHP and nginx X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: php, nginx

Hi I want user to be able to download PDF file from my server (Windows) configured with nginx PHP. This is my nginx.conf (server block)

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile      on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php;

        }

         location /download {
            internal;
            alias /protected;
        }
    }
}
```

..and the PHP file (header part)

```
$file = '/download/real-pdf-file.pdf'; //this is the physical file path
$filename = 'user-pdf-file.pdf'; //this is the file name user will get
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application\pdf');
header('Content-Length: ' .(string)(filesize($file)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('X-Accel-Redirect: '. $file);
```

The file is call from URL like this:

```
download.php?id=a2a9ca5bd4a84294b421fdd9ef5e438ded7fcb09
```

I've try few example/solution from here but so far none is working. The file is large (between 250 to 400 MB each) and each user will be able to download 4 files.

There is no issue with downloading part using PHP, only the nginx configuration that seem not working. No error log detected.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: is `/download/real-pdf-file.pdf` really the absolute path of your file? What's the output of `filesize($file)` in your PHP script? If your PHP is indeed correct, then your nginx configuration is wrong. You tell it: "if the URI `/download/real-pdf-file.pdf` is requested via the `X-Accel-Redirect` header, then serve the file `/protected/read-pdf-file.pdf`". Unless there is a copy of your file (or a file with the same name, or a link), this cannot work.

Comment: PHP will output those as `/download/real-pdf-file.pdf` but the absolute path is `/protected/read-pdf-file.pdf` . I've tried few config but `_ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` from Chrome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok - there's a couple of issues here:

1) Puting root inside of a location is a [BAD IDEA](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block) according to the nginx developers.

2) The internal URL used for telling Nginx that this is an internal redirect shouldn't be exposed to users.

3) I can't see where your download.php file is being served from, so I changed your root location block to use try_files so a request to /download.php would be served by that file rather than index.php.

Your project should be laid out as:

```
project\
    html - this is the root of your website
    protected  - this directory is not accessible directly
```

And your Nginx conf should look like:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile      on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /path/to/project/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location /protected_files {
            internal;
            alias /path/to/project/protected;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a good idea not to re-use the same names to mean different things as it's quite confusing. I've changed them so that now `protected` just refers to the actual physical directory that holds the files you want to serve. `protected_files` is just a string that allows Nginx to match the request from the x-accel header.

The only thing that needs changing in your PHP code is to use the correct string to allow Nginx to pickup the internal location:

```
$aliasedFile = '/download/real-pdf-file.pdf'; //this is the nginx alias of the file path
$realFile = '/path/to/project/protected/real-pdf-file.pdf'; //this is the physical file path
$filename = 'user-pdf-file.pdf'; //this is the file name user will get
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application\pdf');
header('Content-Length: ' .(string)(filesize($realFile)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('X-Accel-Redirect: '. $aliasedFile);
exit(0);
```

Comment: Your solution seem to work but still stuck with the correct syntax for nginx to pick up files from Windows. Google Chrome still return `Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.`. Do we need to set rewrite for download such as `rewrite ^/download/(.*) /download.php?id=$1 last;`?

Comment: I'll accept this as solution, as in Windows we need full file path with forward slash e.g _C:\nginx\file.pdf_ to be fully working.

Answer (score 3):

Based from recommendation and solution from Danack and some clarification from Carsten, I found that in Windows Serve, we need to set the full path in the alias like this:

```
location /protected_files {
            internal;
            alias C:/absolute/path/to/project/protected/;
        }
```

Please note that the extra forward slash is needed (in my case, Windows 7 Pro on development, Windows Server 2008 for deployment). The only issue is now I need to test concurrent downloads to see if server resources is hogging.

I'm new with nginx, since it seem really faster that I switch from Apache. Thanks guy for the enlightenment! I'am glad to be part of Stackoverflow community :)