# php header location vs file_get_contents performace

Tags: php, ajax, caching, header, file-get-contents

I have a website where the client search a term and results are retrieved through an ajax request. On php side, the called script check the date of the cache (cache are files) and if it's older than an established time it refreshes the results, else it return the cache file content: `die(file_get_contents($cache_path));` 
The cache time is a few hours, an to refresh it takes just a few seconds, so the greatest part of the requests will end up in cache response.
So I thought that using `header("location: $cache_path");` would be less stressful for the server, because it simply tells the browser to get the contents from the cache file without passing it through the script. 
The downside is that the cache file path would become public (which is not biggest problem ever, because the content is the same), but, you know, it's never good to give the resources locations...
So, performance wise, is there a big difference between file_get_contents and redirecting? The average cache file size is 120kb... Any other ideas and suggestions?

Comment: The longest part of any request is often network latency and overhead. By redirecting the client you're causing another request, which will likely be slower for them. If you're worried about performance, set up a memory cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "internal redirect": through X-Accel-Redirect header for nginx or X-Sendfile for Apache. In this case you don't show any additional URLs to a client and don't deal with cache files in you script.

For configuration details you can read [an official documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-redirect) or, of course, other SO questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189758/serve-large-file-with-php-and-nginx-x-accel-redirect)).