# Downloading a pdf file using GuzzleHttp Stream

Tags: php, pdf, guzzle

I have a pdf file read from a file system and right now I can display it to the user directly using echo. This is what I did:

```
$file = $client->open($storage_root);
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . 'sample' . '.pdf"');
    header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo ($file->getContents());
```

But I have a requirement to save this file in a temporary location somehow. Any ideas on how I can do that.

Help appreciated!!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by storing the file in a temporary location

Comment: @NadirLatif need to merge this pdf along with other mpdf objects that I have saved on the disk. For this reason I got to save the file on the disk like for ex '/usr/local/temp/xxx.pdf'

Comment: you can use the Php copy function. it copies files from source to destination: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702570/stream-remote-file-with-php-and-guzzle

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you have the contents of the PDF already saved in `$file`? In that case, you can use:

```
<?php

header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . basename($file) . "'"); 

readfile ($file);

?>
```

Hope this helps!